# Program runs without error but output is not coming correct

Tags: java

Hi i am totally a beginner and trying a simple input/output program for practice, the whole programs run in my Eclipse compiler but the result is something like

Enter maintenance expense : 87
Enter School fees: 67
Enter Utility Bills: 98
Enter Grocery expense : 88
Total expense : **88 ( here is the problem  it give the last value i enter)**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class budgetSystem {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static Scanner userInput2;
    public static void main(String[] args){

         int utilityBills = 0;
         int maintainceExp = 0;
         int schoolExp = 0;
         int groceryExp = 0;
         int totalExp = 0;
         userInput2 = new Scanner(System.in);

             System.out.println("Enter Maintaince Expance:");
             utilityBills = userInput2.nextInt();

             System.out.println("Enter School Fees:");
             utilityBills = userInput2.nextInt();

             System.out.println("Enter Utility Bills:");
             utilityBills = userInput2.nextInt();

             System.out.println("Enter Grocery Expance:");
             utilityBills = userInput2.nextInt();

            totalExp= utilityBills + maintainceExp + schoolExp + groceryExp;

             System.out.println("Total Expance: " + totalExp);



    }

} // END OF BUDGET SYSTEM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every step you're reassigning `utilityBills` variable, change your code from:

```
System.out.println("Enter Maintaince Expance:");
utilityBills = userInput2.nextInt();
```

To

```
System.out.println("Enter Maintaince Expance:");
utilityBills += userInput2.nextInt();
```

In every input you take, this would print correct output.

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite the variable `utilityBills` the whole time.

Change your code to:

```
System.out.println("Enter Maintaince Expance:");
 maintainceExp = userInput2.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter School Fees:");
schoolExp = userInput2.nextInt();

 System.out.println("Enter Utility Bills:");
 utilityBills = userInput2.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter Grocery Expance:");
 groceryExp = userInput2.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you scan a value and assigning it back to {utilityBills}, instead set the respective variables in your program. Your last entered value is 88 which is set for {utilityBills} and rest all variables are still zero never set to any value. Change your code as below.

```
 System.out.println("Enter Maintaince Expance:");
             maintainceExp = userInput2.nextInt();

             System.out.println("Enter School Fees:");
             schoolExp = userInput2.nextInt();

             System.out.println("Enter Utility Bills:");
             utilityBills = userInput2.nextInt();

             System.out.println("Enter Grocery Expance:");
             groceryExp = userInput2.nextInt();

            totalExp= utilityBills + maintainceExp + schoolExp + groceryExp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're saving every value in `utilityBills` instead of the correct variables. That's why every other value is 0 and the total is then set to the last entered value.